# Combining PowerShell script to list MailboxName, PrimarySMTPAddress, Who Got Access, AccessPermissions and SizeInMB

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, scripting-language

I want to modify a PowerShell script to export the list of UserMailbox with Full Delegate access of more than one people other than the user itself.

The below script is somehow returns the result:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails UserMailbox | 
Get-MailboxPermission | 
Where-Object { ($_.AccessRights -like "*FullAccess*") -and 
               (-not $_.IsInherited) -and 
               ($_.User -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF") -and 
               ($_.User -notlike '*Discovery Management*') } |
    Select @{Name="User Name";expression={(Get-Recipient $_.User.tostring()).displayname}}, 
            Identity,
            @{Name='Access Rights';Expression={[string]::join(', ', $_.AccessRights)}},
            @{Name="PrimarySMTPAddress";expression={(Get-Recipient $_.User).PrimarySMTPAddress}} | 
        Export-Csv -path C:\EE\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

and

```
$filter = '(Enabled -eq $false) -and (msExchRecipientTypeDetails -ne 4) -and (homeMDB -ne "$null")'
$properties = @('homeMDB', 'mailNickName', 'mail', 'DisplayName', 'SamAccountName', 'ProxyAddresses')

Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties  |
    ForEach-Object {
        $stat = Get-MailboxStatistics $_.SamAccountName

        $smtpAddresses = ($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -like "*smtp:*" }) -replace 'smtp:'

        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
            DisplayName    = $_.DisplayName
            mailNickName   = $_.mailNickName
            SamAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
            mail           = $_.mail
            ProxyAddresses = $smtpAddresses -join ';'
            HomeMDB        = $_.homeMDB.Split(',=')[1]
            MBytes         = $stat.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()
            LastLogonTime  = $stat.LastLogonTime
            LastLoggedOnUserAccount = $stat.SamAccountName
            DisconnectDate = $stat.DisconnectDate
        })
    } | 
    Sort-Object MBytes -Descending | 
    Export-Csv C:\EE\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

But I need some assistance in modifying the additional columns so it will show:

- User Mailbox with Multiple Full Delegate Access: This column will show the Display Name of the mailbox which is accessed by the multiple users. (Display Name only)
- Primary SMTP Address: This column will show the PrimarySMTPAddress of the first column (Identity) or the email address of the mailbox in the first column.
- Who got access: This column shows the usernames of the People who have the UserMailbox (Display Name).
- Access Rights: shows the access right of the delegates. [This is already correct]
- Size in MB: This column will show the size of the mailbox in column 1 in Megabytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might get you going:

```
$filter = '(Enabled -eq $false) -and (msExchRecipientTypeDetails -ne 4) -and (homeMDB -ne "$null")'
$properties = @('homeMDB', 'mailNickName', 'mail', 'DisplayName', 'SamAccountName', 'ProxyAddresses')

Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties  |
    ForEach-Object {
        $stat = Get-MailboxStatistics $_.SamAccountName

        $smtpAddresses = ($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -match "^smtp:" }) -replace 'smtp:', ''

        # Normally, the 'mail' attribute of a user is set to be the Primary email address, but
        # this need not be the case, as Exchange uses the ProxyAddresses attribute.
        # The PrimarySMTPAddress can be extracted from the ProxyAddresses with:
        $primarySmtpAddress = ($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -cmatch "^SMTP:" }) -replace 'SMTP:', ''
        # or by using the EmailAddress property from the user object. 
        # You will then need to add 'EmailAddress' to the '$properties' array above  
        # $primarySmtpAddress = $_.EmailAddress

        # See if there are delegate users and what access rights they have
        $delegates = @(Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $primarySmtpAddress | 
                       Where-Object { ($_.AccessRights -like "*FullAccess*") -and 
                                      (-not $_.IsInherited) -and 
                                      ($_.User -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF") -and 
                                      ($_.User -notlike '*Discovery Management*') } |
                       Select-Object @{Name='Delegate'; Expression={(Get-Recipient $_.User.toString()).DisplayName}}, 
                                     @{Name='AccessRights';Expression={$_.AccessRights -join ', '}})

        ##############################################################################
        # The resulting $delegates is an array, so if you want to only get output for 
        # mailboxes that actually HAVE delegate users, you can uncomment the next line
        ##############################################################################

        # if ($delegates.Count -eq 0) { continue }

        # this can become a LONG column if you want to see the accessrights per user..
        $access = $delegates | ForEach-Object { "{0} ({1})" -f $_.Delegate, ($_.AccessRights -join ', ') }

        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
            DisplayName             = $_.DisplayName
            mailNickName            = $_.mailNickName
            SamAccountName          = $_.SamAccountName
            mail                    = $_.mail
            PrimarySMTPAddress      = $primarySmtpAddress
            ProxyAddresses          = $smtpAddresses -join ';'
            HomeMDB                 = $_.homeMDB.Split(',=')[1]
            MBytes                  = $stat.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()
            LastLogonTime           = $stat.LastLogonTime
            LastLoggedOnUserAccount = $stat.SamAccountName
            DisconnectDate          = $stat.DisconnectDate
            Delegates               = $delegates.Delegate -join ', '        
            AccessRights            = $access -join ', '
        })
    } | 
    Sort-Object MBytes -Descending | 
    Export-Csv C:\EE\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Theo, many thanks for the reply, somehow the script failed: 
Get-ADUser : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context.
At line:9 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties  |
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Difficult to say why this error occurs.. I found an article [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32418.active-directory-troubleshooting-server-has-returned-the-following-error-invalid-enumeration-context.aspx) explaining how `Get-ADUser` in combination with piping to other (lengthy) cmdlets can have a negative effect on the returned data. When piping out AD Objects, the longer the code down the pipeline takes to process, the slower the retrieval of data from Active Directory and eventually the Enumeration Context Expires.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer In addition to this, I don't know how many objects the script has to process through `Get-ADUser`, but you could try adding the `-ResultPageSize` with a value higher than 256 (the default), or by collecting the users in a variable first and loop through that: `$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties; $Users | ForEach-Object { ...}`

Comment: Yes, that does the tricks :-) many thanks Theo ! it works great.